# How to get one spinner values based on the selected value of another spinner when we are working with services

Tags: java, android, service, android-spinner

In my application, I am working with spinners. I want to get values of one spinner based on a selection of an item of another spinner. I searched a lot but I found only custom data. But I am getting those spinner values from services so anybody helps me to solve this.

Here is my code:

```java
//Department spinner
Spinner spinner;
String URL="http://182.18.163.38/def.php?issue=1";
ArrayList<String> Department;
String uid;

//Deficiency category spinner
Spinner spinner2;
String URL2 = "http://182.18.163.38/def.php?issue=2&dept="+uid;
ArrayList<String>Deficiency;
String defid;

//Branch officer spinner
Spinner spinner3;
String URL3 = "http://182.18.163.38/def.php?issue=3";
ArrayList<String> BranchOfficer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_deficiency);

    //spinner for department
    Department = new ArrayList<>();
    spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.select_department);
    loadSpinnerData(URL);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String department = spinner.getItemAtPosition(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),department,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            // DO Nothing here
        }
    });

    //spinner for deficiency
    Deficiency = new ArrayList<>();
    spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.deficiency_category);
    loadSpinnerDeficiency(URL2);

    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String deficiency =   spinner2.getItemAtPosition(spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),deficiency,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            // DO Nothing here
        }
    });
}  

private void loadSpinnerData(String url) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(responseString);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            String department = jsonobject.getString("Department");
            uid = jsonobject.getString("ID");
            Department.add(department);
        }

        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewDeficiency.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Department));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void loadSpinnerDeficiency(String url2) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://182.18.163.38/def.php?issue=2&dept="+uid);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(responseString);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            String defcat = jsonobject.getString("Deficiency");
            defid = jsonobject.getString("ID");
            Deficiency.add(defcat);
        }

        spinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewDeficiency.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Deficiency));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

above is my code for getting values from the url's.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [asynctask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of doing network operations in main thread.

First call the web service to load data for the first spinner,populate data in **onPostExecute()** of the asynctask.

Within the **setOnItemSelectedListener of the first spinner**,take the input from the first spinner(which i believe you are doing) and c**all the asynctask to load the 2nd spinner**.You are not loading the second spinner in the **setOnItemSelectedListener of the first spinner**.